# Locate rectangular in image with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm having trouble with positioning a rectangle in an image. Please see attached photos!

I need to determine the position of the rectangle (black) in the image.

Help me write code with OpenCV. I'm trying to rotate the image based on the black rectangle.

Thank you!

P/s: Because of its ability to present my poor english, hope you understood ignored. Thank you!!

This sample image: http://i.upanh.com/rrkcnu

Comment: Your link to image does not work, host the image on imgur.com, for example. Without sample image is hard to tell which method will work best.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found a method. The information you see here: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/

It can rotate images automatically!!!